# Cannot seem to move from Count (set as default) to other aggregation in Power BI Desktop 2022 December update

Tags: powerbi

I am a beginner at Power BI. I can't seem to figure out how to move out of the Count setting, set as default to other aggregation methods like Sum, Avg, max, min etc.

[image: Example image]

Comment: I think you have an issue with the datatype of your column. Please check. For other aggregations, you need number type data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your column is set as a text or other non-numeric datatype. Check in the Power Query editor the column datatype

[image]

Column1, is set at Text, and will only allow counts, Column2 is set as an Numeric Integer and will allow sum/min/max aggregations

Also you can check in the column tools in the report designer, and see what the data type is set there, you can have in the Power Query editor it set as an numeric, but set here as a text, which can also affect the aggregation types.

[image]